# Looping through pages always gets the same result

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to loop through pages and save a specific image

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

frontstring = 'http://www.haz.de/'

for i in range(1, 50):
    url = 'http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/' \
        + 'Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus#p' + str(i)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
        soup = bs(page)
        galleryimage = soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'pda-fullgallery-large photo'})

        for imgtag in galleryimage:
            try:
                imgurl = frontstring + imgtag['src']
                imgname = 'img/fullgallery-large' + str(i) + '.jpg'
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgurl, imgname)
                print('saving image from ' + imgurl + ' to ' + imgname)
            except Exception as e:
                raise
            else:
                pass
```

However the image is always the same. I don't know where it went wrong. If I open the url in the browser it's the correct page and image but the soup seems to be always the same code. Probably something really stupid and simple but I'm not seeing it after trying really long to find the mistake.

Comment: Hi, you can't download images using python code because image links generated by javascript code. HTML code contains only one link to the same image. Try selenium for example to emulate browser

Comment: I don't think I fully unuderstand what you mean. [#p1](http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus#p2) is another image than [#p1](http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus#p2) or 3, 4, 5 ... 50. I get 50 different pages and then the image. At least that's the idea.

Comment: right but if you open html code for every page you'll find the same image url only, not different as you expect. javascript updates url for each page. but BeautifulSoup can not execute javascript code that is why you save the same image on each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus
http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus/(offset)/1
http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus/(offset)/2
http://www.haz.de/Hannover/Aus-der-Region/Lehrte/Fotostrecken/Digitales-Daumenkino-So-waechst-das-Parkhaus/(offset)/3
```

Those are the real urls, the url you seen is generated by JavaScript. You should disable JavaScrip before you scraping any site